# How to filter for current object on FormView

Tags: python, django, formview

I'm having this urls.py

```
...
    url(r'^storageitem/(?P<pk>[\w]+)/merge/$', login_required(
        StorageItemMergeView.as_view()), name='storage_item_merge'),
...
```

with this view.py

```
...
class StorageItemMergeView(FormView):
    form_class = MergeStorageItemsForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('storage_item_list')
    template_name = 'pmgmt/storageitem/merge.html'
...
```

As the URL might look like localhost:8000/storageitem/155/merge/ I'd like to exclude 155 from the form. I tried to define a custom queryset

```
queryset = StorageItem.objects.exclude(pk=kwargs["pk"])
```

but kwargs is seems not be present at this very point.

```
...
    queryset = StorageItem.objects.exclude(pk=kwargs["pk"])
NameError: name 'kwargs' is not defined
```

What is the correct way to create a FormView based on a model with all items beside the current one?

Answer (score 0):

You can add [get_form_kwargs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) method to your view:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
     kwargs = super(ItemCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
     kwargs.update({
         'exclude_pk' : self.kwargs['pk']
     })
     return kwargs
```

And filter queryset in your form field like this:

```
class MergeStorageItemsForm(Form):
    # Form fields
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exclude_pk = kwargs.pop('exclude_pk')
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if exclude_id:
            self.fields['some_field'].queryset = self.fields['some_field'].queryset.exclude(pk=exclude_pk)
```